# Django allauth and rest framework for account signup and login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I need to make custom views for signup and login implementation on django rest framework for doing rest call.
I have seen the sign-up view and login view provided by allauth which use loginForm and signupForm. But i do not know how to work them out with restframework for api calls. 
Also i need csrf token security.
Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doc can help you: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

It's a login form with DRF and csrf token :)

Comment: I don't want html. I want api calls.

Comment: Like this ? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: Yes, but it's very basic to work with django-allauth. Allauth guys have good formViews but i think they are not usable with rest framework. Take a look at django-rest-auth. In particular, their registration/views.py

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py